# How can I display a button in front of each array value separately?

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects stored in my main component(to avoid using redux). When I display the tasks, the list comes as a single entity, just like a paragraph. I want to separate each task and add two buttons in front of each task.

[image]

this is my code to display the array of objects

[image]

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code or other text. Copy the original text to your question.

Comment: Create a button and onclick pass the id and do whatever you want.

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Should have code in text so we can copy and paste